# What is the correct title of Sara Coleridge's poem about the months?

Tags: poetry, title, sara-coleridge

Sara Coleridge's poem begins:

> January brings the snow
> makes our feet and fingers glow

I have seen this listed as:

- The Garden Year
- The Months
- January brings the snow

What is the correct / original title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The poem first appeared in print in Coleridge’s collection *Pretty Lessons in Verse for Good Children: With Some Lessons in Latin in Easy Rhyme* (1834). Google Books has a scan of an [1839 edition](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Pretty_Lessons_in_Verse_for_Good_Childre/dJUNAAAAQAAJ), where the poem [starts on page 7](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Pretty_Lessons_in_Verse_for_Good_Childre/dJUNAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA7) under the title ‘**The Months**’:

[image: PRETTY LESSONS. THE MONTHS. January brings the snow, Makes our feet and fingers glow etc.]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if she re-published at a later date under the title The Garden Year, or was that someone else?

Comment: @PhilPreen All the editions I found prior to her death in 1852 use the title "The Months". I doubt she would have used the title "The Garden Year" as lakes, sheep, corn, sportsmen, and pheasants are not normally found in gardens.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess The Garden Year is a later reworking by someone else. I didn't look closely enough to see if it was actually a different version of the poem.